# Make Scrollbar Max as long? - Vb6

Tags: vb6, scroll, integer, scrollbar, long-integer

I was working on my vb6 project, and I needed my scrollbar max to reach 40000. Though I can assume that the max was around 32000 since the scrollbar max is an integer. How can I change this?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to do that?  Consider setting the range from 0 to 100, or 0 to 1000 (percentage of your document's size, basically), and scaling from that to the range that you need.

**EDIT:** For example, if you have a document with 40,000 lines, set the scrollbar maximum to 100.  When you read the value, multiply it by the ratio of the document size over the maximum size of the scrollbar.  When the scrollbar thumb is in the middle at 50, you'll get 50 * (40,000 / 100), or 20,000.

You'll have to use a `long` in VB6.

Comment: He means that you can configure the min and max of the scroll bar to a  value held in an integer, then change how THAT value changes during scrolling.

Comment: Exactly.  Something like `position = scrollbarPosition * (docSize / scrollbarmax)`

Comment: Wouldn't that scroll 400 lines at a time when you hit the little arrows? Not fun.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the max value over 32767 because it is of Integer type and that is its maximum value for 32 bits Integer. My solution is to stablish

```
Dim lCurrentLine as Long 
Dim dblMultiplier as Double
Dim lPreviousValue as Long
```

While your resulset is lower or equal than 32767 you can set

```
dblMultiplier = 1
vScrollBar1.Min = 1
vScrollBar1.Max = ResulSet.Count
```

When it gets bigger you set:

```
dblMultiplier = Resulset.Count / 32767 

vScrollBar1.Min = 1
vScrollBar1.Max = 32767
```

When you obtains the value scrolling directly the scrollbar you should apply the multiplier

```
lCurrentLine = vScrollBar1.Value * dblMultiplier
```

So you will have always a position, but as it means that when dblMultiplier is bigger than 1 there will be more lines than scrollbarpositions, you should capture the change event and evaluate when you have done a smallchange. Something like that:

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Change()
    If Abs(VScrollBar1.Value - lPreviousValue) = VScrollBar1.SmallChange Then
        If Sgn(VScrollBar1.Value - lPreviousValue) >= 0 Then
            'That means we have increased the value
            lCurrentLine = lCurrentLine + VScrollBar1.SmallChange
            If lCurrentLine > Resulset.Count Then lCurrentLine = Resulset.Count
        Else
            'That means we have decreased the value
            lCurrentLine = lCurrentLine - VScrollBar1.SmallChange
            If lCurrentLine < 1 Then lCurrentLine = 1
        End If
    Else
        lCurrentLine = VScrollBar1.Value * dblMultiplier
    End If
    'That captures the scrollbar current value for future changes
    lPreviousValue = VScrollBar1.Value
End Sub
```